# how to move legend after using hue in searborn lmplot?

Tags: python

I an trying to move legend after using hue= for seaborn lmplot(). If I use plt.legend(loc=1), it will create 2nd legend.

```
g=sns.lmplot(x=x,y=y,data=df1,hue='AREA',fit_reg=False,height=10, aspect=1,scatter_kws={"s": 200})
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `legend=False` in the lmplot call.

```
g=sns.lmplot(x=x,y=y,data=df1,hue='AREA',legend=False,fit_reg=False,height=10, aspect=1,scatter_kws={"s": 200})
```

Then move the legend to another place like
`plt.legend(loc='upper left')` or `plt.legend(loc='upper right')`

Comment: Yes it works, thanks Priya. However this legend from plt. doesn't have legend title which is same name as hue. Is it possible to add hue name into legend title? Thanks

Comment: yeah, you can do 
`plt.legend(loc='upper left', title="smoker", fancybox=True)` where `smoker` is the name of the column used as `hue` in the plot.